# Query on SQL Server 2014's sys.partitions DMV take too long

Tags: sql-server, performance, dmv

Although in normal conditions, running the following query would take much less than **1** second, now it takes between **35** to **58** seconds.

```
use myOffendingDatabaseName
select count(*) from sys.partitions
```

We are just trying to figure out why is this system query so slow, since

Further information:

- Analysing execution plan ([provided here](https://pastebin.com/7acBcWdP)) using **SentryOne's Plan Explorer** (I am not affiliated), I had found that while there were **4253** **Estimated Rows** on one **sys.sysrowsets** operation, **Actual Rows** is **20094**, which led me to outdated system view statistics;
- There are no other processes charging CPU or I/O;
- Although this query will return aproximately a count of **20.000**
  items on **sys.partitions** system view on this database, on other
  servers such a complex database takes less than one second;
- Running the same query on simpler (**<500** partitions) databases on the name SQL Server instance, takes the expected time of less than **1** second.
- **SQL SERVER 2014 Express** (12.0.6024.0);
- **Windows Server 2016** with 16 GB Memory (although SQL Server express version is limited to 4 GB);

Can you give a clue to follow ?

Comment: You need to have SQL recalculate statistics based on the current data -- this is a maintenance process all DBs need.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, @Hogan, after executin **EXEC sp_updatestats** on offending database, solved it. Thanks

Comment: Here is the [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1VekaZ3B) for this plan.

Comment: What a great tip! Thanks! @LaughingVergil